# C++: Getline ignores "\n" in mqtt message

Tags: c++, bash, mosquitto

I use a mqtt message to send messages like this: `mosquitto_pub -t "TOPIC1" -m "ARG1\nARG2\n"`

In my C++ application i write:

```
string payload = reinterpret_cast<char*>(message->payload);
std::istringstream iss(payload);
std::string arg1;
std::getline(iss, arg1);
cout << arg1 << endl;
```

This gives me `ARG1\nARG2\n`. What's wrong here?

Comment: It's not ignoring anything, It's just that your payload literally contains the pair of characters `\n`, whereas you wrongly expected it to interpret that to mean 'newline' like it does if encountered in source code. What shell are you using, and does it also treat `\m` in a quoted string to mean newline?

Comment: i'm using the regular bash

Comment: I made some change to this line, then it worked.

    string payload = "ARG1\nARG2\n";

so I suggest to debug before this line

Comment: yes, when I define this string inside the code then it works. But it looks identical to the string that is in the mqtt message

Comment: Sometimes hiding behind the visual representation of `\n` is `\r\n`

Comment: @m_3464gh read again first comment [see this](https://godbolt.org/z/sqG18z) and read about [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and its [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Comment: `printf %s "ARG1\nARG2\n"`  Now `printf %s $'ARG1\nARG2\n'`.  Nothing to do with your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a C++ problem.

Your problem is that normally `\n` is not interpreted as new line in by bash for a command line argument. Also mosquitto_pub will not do any interpretation on the input message.

You can force this as follows:

```
mosquitto_pub -t "TOPIC1" -m $'ARG1\nARG2\n'
```